# css variables :root vs :host

Tags: css, shadow-dom

Just starting with webdevelopment (coming from android)
in my project I tried to assign variables  as in many tutorial is mentions with help of ":root" :

```
:root {
  --accentColor: #20a8d8;
  --primary: #96a1a5;
  --secondary: #415a72;
  --bgColorrr:#1e2e38;
}
```

But that did not work at all.
After changing it to ":host" it work though - can someone please explain what is the reason behind :root not working?

May be worth mention: I used that on my custom component (Angular 5) and I'm using CoreUI (in case that may effect some CSS)

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're talking about **Shadow DOM**. Elements can get a new kind of node associated with them. This new kind of node is called a **shadow root**. An element that has a shadow root associated with it is called a **shadow host**. The content of a shadow host isn’t rendered; the content of the shadow root is rendered instead. There's this thing called **Style Encapsulation**.

[image: SHADOW DOM]

Also I would suggest avoiding the use of **:root**. I know the docs say to use **:root** and technically I think that's fine to do at the document level, but you are using a framework maybe there is a conflict inside of the Shadow DOM and cause a bug. Avoiding **:root** all together might just be a good habit to get into. @pb4now correct me if I'm totally wrong about stuff.

Here's more info about [Shadow DOM](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom) and read more about Angular Style Components. Hope it helps.

Comment: ty very much sir ! helps alot(y)